# Android open source activity to let the user select/create a media?

Tags: android, video, audio, camera, android-gallery

In my open source app, I want to let users insert a **picture/video/sound/etc**. The user can either select an existing media from the **SD card** **or** use the **device's hardware** (take a photo, record a video, record a sound, draw on touchscreen) if they prefer to create a new media.

There are plenty of code snippets showing how to implement each of these things, but rather than re-inventing the wheel, is there a **library that handles the whole activity of choosing a media file?** I would just call this library, it would handle the UI, and return me the filepath to the media the user selected/created.

Here is how it could look like:

[image: Android media chooser]

I am sure many apps would find this widget useful (CMS authoring, wysiwyg, sharing apps, rich chat, ...). As an LGPL (or public domain) component, I am sure it would be popular and gather a community of developers. Before I launch this project, is there already such a gadget?

Comment: As I searched but couldnt find such jar but found all required snippets
so,Just suggestion

Nicolas, I just wonder that why dont you go and collect all the snippets required to get media from sdcard or record or capture new files, which are surely available on internet in different blogs [May be you can find all the code in StackOverflow answers only.!]

Then you will need to make only different Java file/Methods for each and once test that using ExampleActivity..and then Export all that java files as jar and then you will have your own jar to do the tasks.

Comment: @FasteKerinns: If the gadget I described exists already, it would be much smarter to use it, rather than gathering random snippets and making sure they work on all recent Android versions (which takes much more time than one might think). Rather collaborate than re-invent the wheel :-) I would be surprised if such a gadget does not already exists.

Comment: Yeh reading your question i am also trying to search for the same, will send you the link if i get any one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a small Android Library Project, called *aFileChooser*, that aims to streamline the selection part of this process. It includes a built-in file explorer, and returns a `File` object after selection. You can also retrieve the image or video thumbnail, and use helper methods to get the URI and path.

Disclaimer: I haven't had a chance to test this with ICS, but it should function properly.

https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser

Finding an all-in-one solution with capture may not be as easy, as this is one of the areas where fragmentation is real.

Comment: Very nice! You are right that this is an area where fragmentation makes things difficult. Especially for testing. Making sure this patchwork of snippets is reliable on many devices takes a lot of time (maybe ~5 days per month). And that's exactly why I think collaboration is better than doing it alone.

Comment: Awarding bounty because I will use your library if I have no choice but create my own media selection/creation activity. But still hoping someone finds what I am looking for...

Comment: Reading your library made me understand that what I really need is a call to `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. That will let the user choose an image from the gallery, record a sound, etc depending on which apps are installed.

Answer (score 3):

For [taking a picture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), use this Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

For [taking video](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE), use this Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE );
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

For [recording audio](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html#RECORD_SOUND_ACTION), use this Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION );
startActivityForResult( intent );
```

You, of course, would have to design the Activity to pick which action they would like to perform. See the linked documentation for retrieving the file path when the Activity returns.

Comment: If the gadget I described in my question exists already, it would be much smarter to use it, rather than gathering random snippets and making sure they work on all recent Android versions (which takes much more time than one might think). Rather collaborate than re-invent the wheel :-) I would be surprised if such a gadget does not already exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "gadget"? Using these action intents means you use the built-in apps for performing these functions, thus avoiding reinventing the wheel.

Comment: And all 3 action intents I've listed will work back to Cupcake, meaning they will work for [99.7%](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) of devices.

Comment: Indeed, I reckon that these 3 actions are much cleaner than random snippets. I will use them if I have no choice but create my own media selection/creation activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OI File Manager for Android is an open file manager that seamlessly cooperates with other applications http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159

Comment: Its PICK_FILE intent is indeed something that could be used if I wanted to have only "Pick file from the SD card", but my question is about an activity that would also allow the user to take a picture/video/sound if they want, rather than selecting an existing file.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul You did say OR (and actually made it bold).

Comment: I meant the user can either select an existing file OR create a new one. User can choose. Sorry if it was unclear, I make it more explicit.